# Total Number of 3x3 matrices using only digits 1 to 9

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, combinations

Consider a 3$\times$3 matrix which can only be made up of single digits, for example the matrix below satisfies these conditions (no repeating of digits).
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 2 &3 \\ 
 4& 5 &6 \\ 
 7& 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}

How many different unique matrices can be created just using these digits ? I think the answer is 9! Is my intuition correct ?

Comment: Can we repeat digits?

Comment: It is correct only if you must use every digit once and only once.

Comment: Why matrices when you can present your question in ordered tuples?

Comment: Observe that $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}\cong\Bbb R^9$, thus we can think in vectors of length $9$ instead of $3\times 3$ matrices.

If we can use each number only once then the result is, as you find, $9!$.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to mention that, we can only repeat the digits once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. You are arranging 9 unique objects into 9 positions. There are 9 ways of placing the first, 8 ways of placing the second, etc.

This represents what is called a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). Note that the fact the nine items are arranged in a $3\times 3$ fashion is not relevant.